# Checking the Annotation name in the view

Tags: jsp, annotations, jstl, el

In the code below, the objective is, with the object passed to the view (command), its fields (`${fields}`) and the annotations of each one of the fields(`${annotations}`), generate the form for insert a new object of a certain type (class).

My question is how to access the value of the attribute `simpleName` from each annotation. In java code, I would use: `annotation.getAnnotationType().getSimpleName()`, but when I try this on the jsp (`${item2['annotationType'].simpleName`), I get an error: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'annotationType' not found on type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96`.

Anyone can tell me how to make this:

```
    <custom:MainForm action="${cadastra}" classe="${command['class'].simpleName}">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${fields}" varStatus="status">
            <custom:FieldBox ordem="${status.index}">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <custom:Label/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <c:forEach var="item2" items="${annotations}">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'Input'}">
                                <custom:Input/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'Select'}">
                                <c:url value="/.../listagem.json" var="url"/>
                                <custom:Select lista="${url}"/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'EmbedSelect'}">
                                <c:url value="/.../listagem.json" var="url"/>
                                <c:url value="/.../cadastra" var="cad"/>
                                <c:url value="/.../altera" var="alt"/>
                                <c:url value="/.../remove" var="del"/>
                                <custom:EmbedSelect lista="${url}" cadastra="" altera="" remove=""/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'Textarea'}">
                                <custom:Textarea/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'Checkbox'}">
                                <custom:Checkbox/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${item2['annotationType'].simpleName == 'Radiobutton'}">
                                <custom:Radiobutton/>
                            </c:when>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </custom:FieldBox>
        </c:forEach>
        <div class="row field-box">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </custom:MainForm>
```